# Change Password Option in NAPILI Template - Salesforce communities

Tags: napili

I am not able to see the ChangePassword Option when the user is logged in.

In the community builder ,
In Login registration section, I have linked the changepassword VF page from Salesforce and then published the site as well , 
I have also made the changepassword page in salesforce sites as public.

Can anyone please let me know where can i enable the change password button and where should i be able to see the change password button